# Runescape - What comes after batwing armor for pure mage f2p characters?

Tags: runescape

I'm currently playing a pure mage f2p character and I'm approaching batwing armor. After looking around a bit, I cant seem to find the next tier. I know mystic armor exists but it's roughly the same level as batwing armor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually they aren't the same. Mystic is better.

[Batwing](https://runescape.wiki/w/Batwing_robes) is tier 30 armour, while [mystic](https://runescape.wiki/w/Mystic_robes) is tier 50.

There's also [battle robes](https://runescape.wiki/w/Battle_robes) which have recently become F2P, and they give a magic offence bonus.

Comment: I just realized that mystic is bought in a members area, is there any f2p way to get it or any other f2p robes I can get? I would get the battle robes but I've never done the Fist of Guthix. Do they take long to get? Also, if batwing is the highest tiered set of normally-acquired robes, that is kind of disappointing.

Comment: @ryzehalberd Batwing used to be the highest but it isn't anymore. To obtain Mystic, I think you can only buy it from the Grand Exchange. I'd say Battle Robes take quite a while to go for, especially if Fist of Guthix is still played often on F2P (I'm not sure what the player base is like).

Comment: @TerryA What about splitbark at tier 40? It is F2P now as well.

Answer (score 0):

mystic is purchased in the champions guild south of Varrock. 33 QP required for entry

Comment: Do you have a source? The wiki states that they can be purchased in the Mage's guild not the Champion's guild.

Comment: @KyleRone Based on the [Patch Notes](http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Update:Patch_Notes_(4_December_2017)), it looks like Mystic gear is now available at the Champions Guild as of 12/4/2017

Comment: Ahhh thats why I didnt know about that. Havent played the main game in some time. t

Comment: Saw it in there recently on the second floor, thought it was a bit weird and didn't remember it being there either